# 14.04 battery died during apt-get upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I did my daily apt-get update and upgrade, but I forgot to plug in my laptop to a power source and battery died during upgrade. After pluging in and turning laptop on everything froze. So now ubuntu 14.04 wont load. It stops at loading logo. Is there anything I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried booting into recovery mode (via grub)?

Once in recovery mode you could do:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Since you may have packages that are partially installed, you may want to run:

```
    sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

before updating and upgrading from grub.